# Sub project dependent on root project in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

Can sub project dependent on or use some files or packages from the root project in gradle?

I have the following project:

```
root
├── project1
├── build.gradle
└── src
├── settings.gradle
```

I have the `settings.gradle` as following:

```
include 'project1'
```

The project1 need to use some files and packages from `src` of the `root` which is the root project, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this structure as it's more flexible and manageable. **root** will be just a wrapper and will contain subprojects only.

```
root
├── project1 (dependent on project 2)
|   |
|   |__build.gradle
|    
|
|__ project2
|   |
|   |__ src
|   |__ build.gradle
|   
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include 'project1'
include 'project2'
```

**EDIT:**
If you need to have dependency on root, use following dependency in **project1**:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':root')
}
```

In **settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'root'
include 'project1'
```

Comment: it is a big project, are there any way to use the files and packages from the root package based on the current?

Comment: it says: Project with path ':root' could not be found in project ':project1' after adding it to the dependency in project build.gradle